# How to get the finding links from the post content

Tags: post

I need some help in finding links in html code.

```
  function get_content_link( $content = false, $echo = false ){

  if ( $content === false )
        $content = get_the_content(); 

   $content = preg_match_all('#[\'"]https?://([^/]+\.)*example.com/[^\'"]*[\'"]#siU', $content, $links );

    $content = $links[1][0];

    if ( empty($content) ) {
        $content = false;
    }

    return $content;
   }
```

This doesn't work as it should I'm afraid. I don't know what is wrong because have no experience with preg_match.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The variable content contains there different things in your code : The content itself, the number of links and the links themselves. Good practice is to use each variable for only one thing. Or you get unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer

To help for all

```
function get_Example( $content = false, $echo = false ){
    if ( $content === false )
    $content = get_the_content(); 
    $regexp = '/href=\"https:\/\/example\.com\/([^\"]*)"/i';
    if(preg_match_all($regexp, $content, $link)) {
        $content = $link[1][0];
}
    if ( empty($content) ) {
        $content = false;
    }
    return $content;
}
```